# Jquery TokenInput: Turning a belongs_to select menu into the token field

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**This has been completed all code below is working.**

If your familiar with the [R.B Rails Cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields) that was done on this i am instead trying to work with the "@authorships" form instead of the Book-to-Author itself.

I am using [Jquery TokenInput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) and this is my setup in more detail:

---

Application.js

```
$(function() {
  $("#user_product_product_token").tokenInput("/products.json", {
    prePopulate: $("#user_product_product_token").data("pre"),
    tokenLimit: 1
  });
});
```

---

```
class UserProduct
    attr_accessible :product_token, :price
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :product
    attr_reader :product_token

    def product_token=(id)
        self.product_id = id
    end
end
```

---

```
class Product
    has_many :user_products
    has_many :users, :through => :user_products
end
```

---

This gets my `/products.json` route to work and list all of my products with ID and Name.

```
class ProductsController

  def index
    @products = Product.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @products.map(&:attributes) } # This here
    end
  end
```

This is my form:

```
<%= form_for(@user_product) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :product_token, "data-pre" => @products.map(&:attributes).to_json %>
    <%= f.label :price %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
class UserProductsController

def new
    @user_product = current_user.user_products.build
    # This just initializes the @products variable for the @products.map and ProductsController.
    @products = []
 end

def edit
    @user_product = UserProduct.find(params[:id])
    # Without this line below it cant find the correct product.
    @products = [@user_product.product]
end
```

Here's my gist on it: https://gist.github.com/1116092

Comment: It seems that `@products = nil`. Could you show the controller action which should set this instance variable?

Comment: @polarblau I Edited my answer to include the Products Controller which is the one that should set the instance variable.

Comment: Looks like a problem with routes to me, can you gist the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: @Rubish Gupta Alright, here you go: https://gist.github.com/1121374

Comment: Sorry, the routes look fine. Are you sure you initiating the variable `@products` in the action which renders the form?

Comment: It’s still sorta hard to guess what’s going on there, but you don’t need the `map(&:attributes)` IMO. Using if your controller only responds to JSON you could replace the whole `respond_to` block with `render :json => @products` which will invoke `#as_json` automatically. You might also want to append `.all` to your `where` query to ensure that your results are actually loaded: `@products = Product.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%").all`.

Comment: @Rubish Gupta No I'm not. How would i do that? I am using my UserProduct form. All i know i can render the products.json page and see all of my products perfectly.

Comment: The "data-pre" => @products.map(&:attributes) lets me repopulate the field with my products i created with my prices. I still cannot use the form, i still get the Nil Object. I am trying to keep the @products. If i can do that then i get it all to work.

Comment: Can you post the contents of action which renders the form?

Comment: @Rubish Gupta OK, check out my EDIT area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@products` instance variable is not set, as already pointed out by Luke, but but his solution to it is not probably what you want. You want to pre-populate the product if some is already selected in `UserProduct`. which would not be set as your are creating a new `UserProduct` in the action, but if you use same form with edit also, then it might be used. I would suggest to modify your action on following lines in both `new` and `edit` action:

```
def new
  @user_product = current_user.user_products.build
  @products = [@user_product.product]

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @user_product }
  end
end
```

One other thing you need to take care is, set the `max` option while initializing jquery-token-input to `1`, as you can have one user_product belong to only one product.

One other thing I noticed is your method to save product_token, you misssed the actual assignment there:

```
def product_token=(id)
    self.product_id = id # assign it to product_id
end
```

Comment: I still get the nil object when i put the following code in the new method.

Comment: Putting @products = Product.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
in the new method works but it shows all of my products in the database. It should not do that, it should do as you say, populate only the 1 product in the Edit, no Pre-populating while creating the Prices for products.

Comment: I added in image to help and edited my question to solve this area of the problem.

Comment: Yeah i did, everything up there is fresh and lets be search for the products but if you take a look at the image, i unfortunately get that.

Comment: try changing `@products = [@user_product.product]` to `@products = []`

Comment: in my NEW route it does get rid of the products and its exactly how i want but this doesn't pre-populate the Product in the EDIT route. I have tried putting @products = [] but no good.

Comment: Thank you, i was able to get to work by inserting in the EDIT action: @products = [@user_product.product].

Answer (score 2):

The instance variable `@products` is `nil` when you render the form because you never instantiate it in the `new` action of `UserProductsController`. Try this:

```
class UserProductsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user_product = current_user.user_products.build
    @products = Product.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user_product }
    end
  end

end
```